# Clear browser cache, history, and cookies

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, linkedin-api

I implemented the Facebook/LinkedIn connect and they are working fine on [Windows Phone 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone_7) emulator. However, my problem is that when I want to authenticate and get the `access_token` for a different user, I'm not able to do that.

I read on some blogs that the solutions would be to clear the cookies related to Facebook and LinkedIn requests.
If this solves my problem, can you explain how is it doable, and if not what is the solution then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the problem is it's using the existing session (cookies). Check out *[WP7 Facebook Logout Issues](http://dotnetcatch.wordpress.com/2011/08/26/wp7-facebook-logout-issues/)*. It explains how to accomplish this for both for Facebook and Twitter. I'm not sure how you would do LinkedIn, but judging by these two it should be similar.